# Auto-generation of bibliography based on DOI

Tags: bibliographies

I'm sick of curating my own .bib files. I know there are services that will translate a DOI into bibtex data. But I don't want to do this myself, I want my LaTeX compiler to do it. Is there a package that will do this?

Ideally I would enter a bibtex key and the DOI, and the package would do everything else.